# Mercurial extdiff one at a time

Tags: mercurial, diff

I am using winmerge as my extdiff tool, like this:

```
[extdiff]
cmd.winmerge = C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe
opts.winmerge = /e /x /ub /wl
```

The thing is, when I run `hg winmerge` it seems that it sends all of the files at once, while for example in Git, when I do a `diff` it calls the difftool with one modified file at a time. Can I get the same behaviour in Mercurial?

Comment: What do you mean by "all of the files at once" ? extdiff creates a snapshot of the modification and send it to the diff tool as a directory. Maybe try adding the `/r` option to winmerge...

Comment: @Krtek Is there some way extdiff could be configured not to send the modification as a directory, but as separate files?

Comment: There's no configuration option AFAIK, but I added an answer involving an intermediate script to do the job...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like explained in [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/adding-functionality-with-extensions.html#sec:hgext:extdiff), extdiff creates two snapshot of the source tree and call the diff tool on them. You're tool has to support directory diff for it to work, but like explained, you can use scripting to workaround this.

[This example script](https://bitbucket.org/bos/hgbook/src/8767e1ad0383/contrib/hg-interdiff) is given in the book. It basically takes the two directories and call the `interdiff` utility on every files.

In your case, you can easily adapt the script to call `winmerge` instead. Just modify the line 41 :

```
if os.system('winmerge /e /x /ub /wl "%s" "%s"' % (name(sys.argv[1], f),
```

Say you create an hg-winmerge script , you can then configure extdiff like this :

```
 [extdiff]
 cmd.winmerge = C:\Path\To\My\Script\hg-winmerge
```

Hope this helps !