# Getting the 2 folders in the temp directory while doing a diff in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, diff

My understanding is when we do a diff using mercurial it creates 2 temporary folders- one for each revision being compared against:
[Mercurial/extdiff not changing to temp dir (as I THINK it's supposed to)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293223/mercurial-extdiff-not-changing-to-temp-dir-as-i-think-its-supposed-to)

I know how to set up a external diff(say EXTDIFFTOOL) tool using the mercurial .ini file. My problem is: How can I let my EXTDIFFTOOL take 2 arguments: one each for the temp folders.